# Отображение окна поверх полноэкранных приложений (игр)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xml

Отображение окна поверх полноэкранных приложений (игр)

Возможно ли отобразить окно поверх игры которая запущенна в полноэкранном режиме, типа как имеет тоже свойство Topmost, почему игра в этом случае перекрывает мое окно, почему приоритет дается игре, возможно ли получить приоритет моему приложению, чтобы оно было поверх всех полноэкранных игр?

Заранее спасибо, если поможете!

Comment: В настоящем полноэкранном режиме нет понятия "окно", отрисовка происходит напрямую в буфер экрана.

Comment: SetForeGroundWindow

Comment: Где это нужно вписать? Можно пример